# The Brute Force Algorithm for findning word in a string

Tags: string, algorithm, brute-force

I have this string ABECCACBABDABBAD
How can I use the brute force algorithm for finding word ABBAD in the string above?

Thank you all

Comment: find all the combination of strings and match with your input word

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Maybe consider a [Rabin-Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) or [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) string searching algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

To brute force find `ABBAD` in `ABECCACBABDABBAD` loop through `ABECCACBABDABBAD` till `A` is found.

1. If A is found check if the next character is B
2. if the next character is B check if the character after is B
3. if the next character is B check if the character after is A
4. if the next character is A check if the character after is D

If all the checks pass then you brute force found your `ABBAD`

Answer (score 0):

Naive string matching algorithm from CLRS:

```
NAIVE-STRING-MATCHER(T, P)
  n = T.length
  m = P.length
  for s = 0 to n - m
     if P[1..m] == T[s + 1..s + m]
        return TRUE
  return FALSE
```